# Prove that a limit of an integral function is finite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove that the following limit is finite
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to b}\int_a^x \left(\int_\xi ^x (b-y)^{-\alpha}e^{-2y} dy \right)(b-\xi)^{-(1-\alpha)}e^{2 \xi} d \xi
\end{equation}
I'm in the case $0<\alpha < 1$, then I know that for every $\xi \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}_+, a \ne 0$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to b} \int_\xi ^x (b-y)^{-\alpha}e^{-2y} dy< \infty
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to b} \int_a^x  (b-\xi)^{-(1-\alpha)}e^{2 \xi} d \xi< \infty
\end{equation}
From this two fact can I conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to b}\int_a^x \left(\int_\xi ^x (b-y)^{-\alpha}e^{-2y} dy \right)(b-\xi)^{-(1-\alpha)}e^{2 \xi} d \xi < \infty
\end{equation}
Or what I need to conclude?

Comment: You've left out hypotheses on $f,g$. Please state them.

Comment: @zhw sorry, you are right. I edited the post.

Comment: Continuous functions on  [a,b] are automatically integrable there. And f is not defined on [a,b]. It's defined on $[a,b]\times [a,b)$ or at least it looks that way to me. The hypotheses are still not coherent.

Comment: @zhw. precisely, I have to compute $\lim_{x \to b} \int_a^x (\int_\xi^x (b-y)^{- \alpha}e^{-2y}dy) (b-\xi)^{-(1-\alpha)}e^{2 \xi} d\xi$. I'm in the case $\alpha < 1$ and so the two limit state in the question are finite. I have to prove that the entire limit is finite...

Comment: You need to edit the question. Be clear, precise, and complete. I don't think this is too much to ask.

Comment: @zhw. this is precisesly my question. Before i tried to semplify the statement. Sorry if this was not the case.

Comment: Is $0<\alpha < 1?$

Comment: Yes, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you want in the newly stated problem is true, and it's simple. Every thing in sight is positive, so your iterated integral is an increasing function of $x.$ And for any $x\in [a,b]$ this integral is bounded above by

$$\int_a^b \int_a ^b (b-y)^{-\alpha}e^{-2y} (b-\xi)^{-(1-\alpha)}e^{2 \xi} \, dy \, d \xi .$$

Because $0< \alpha < 1,$ the last integral converges; this is easy to check, because it is the product of two convergent integrals. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $[0,1]$ and
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{1-x}, & x<1\\
0, &x=1
\end{cases}$$
and $f(\xi,x)=F(\xi)$. Clearly $f$ is real and bounded for every $\xi\in[0,1]$

Take $g(\xi)=1$ the constant function, and clearly $\int_0^xg(\xi)d\xi$ is bounded for every $x\in[0,1]$.

But 
$$\lim_{x\to1}\int_0^xf(\xi,x)g(\xi)d\xi=\lim_{x\to1}\int_0^xF(\xi)d\xi$$ is clearly not integrable.

My guess would be to ask for continuity of $f$.

Comment: Of all the functions you could choose, you actually chose an $F$ that is integrable. Try $F(\xi) = 1/x, x\in (0,1], F(0) = 0$ instead.